# What's your favourite quote about programming?

Tags: quotations

What's your favourite quote about programming?

**One quote per answer**, and please [check for duplicates](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion:39+your+search+terms+here) before posting!

Answer (score 231):

> Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.

— Brian W. Kernighan

Comment: Everytime I'm writing some clever bit of code, I remind myself of this rule and look back over it to see if I can't do things in a simpler way that will be easier to maintain later, or at least add some more comments.

Comment: A corolloary of an otherwise true maxim: Don't forget that a diagram can increase your brain power. You can swap out "remember structure of big thing" to nonvolatile paper.

Comment: I love the quote but the implication is that we should at most put 50% of our effort into coding in the first place.

Comment: I think the implication is that you should avoid that programmer's urge to use the 'clever' way to do something when the slightly longer, more obvious way of doing something works just fine.

Comment: But what if it's "perfect" code? There's no way to "debug" that.

Answer (score 183):

> Walking on water and developing software
>   from a specification are easy if both
>   are frozen.

— Edward V Berard

Comment: Quote of the year, I'm gonna use this one

Comment: I hate this one. It's never the case, so who cares?

Answer (score 138):

> It always takes longer than you
>   expect, even when you take into
>   account Hofstadter's Law.
>   
>   — [Hofstadter's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter%27s_law)

Comment: Brain stack overflow.

Comment: @Joe D: I'm curious how you'd rewrite a recursive *English* sentence into a single non-recursive sentence.

Comment: It may converge for sufficient small values of "longer"

Comment: +1 - I'm proud to count myself among the top billion programmers along with Douglas Hofstadter.

Comment: @g.f: When it's transformed into defining the source afterwards (with a dash), the leading introduction isn't warranted ("A: Blah." -> "Blah. -- A").  This isn't removing part of the quote.

Comment: @Roger: In this case it takes away part of the intent for me: *"A: Even if A"*.

Comment: @g.f: If you want to edit it that way without the redundancy (e.g. *not* "A: Blah. -- A", but "A: Blah."), I wouldn't revert it, but I think it's fine like this too.

Answer (score 126):

> Always code as if the guy who ends up
>   maintaining your code will be a
>   violent psychopath who knows where you
>   live.

— Rick Osborne

Comment: it seems I keep ending up maintaining code that I wish I knew where the creator lived, but its probably a good thing I don't.

Comment: Brings new meaning to the term "killer app." I seem to always end up maintaining the psychopath's code after he's incarcerated.

Comment: @webbiedave You work on ReiserFS? :)

Comment: The company must really hate you if the killer got your job.

Answer (score 118):

> You can have the project:
>
> - Done On Time
> - Done On Budget
> - Done Properly
>
> Pick two.

— Unknown

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_triangle

Comment: Reminds me of a similar triangle, but with women.  "You can have a girlfriend that: Is smart, is attractive, has a good personality."

Comment: Don't forget that exceptions do exist, though they're rare - don't count on it.

Comment: Faster, Better, Cheaper - Pick 2. If you are very lucky !

Comment: @Maxpm: The version I heard was "The 4 S's: Smart, Sexy, Sane, Single.  Pick 3."

Comment: So, when there are no constraints on time and budget you cannot do it properly. Good to know.

Comment: @Antsan You mean,when there ARE constraints on time and budget,you can't do it properly

Comment: @Antsan: This can be true, since you'd always want to polish your baby "that little bit more". Look at Duke Nukem Forever.

Answer (score 111):

> Some people, when confronted with a
>   problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions."
>   Now they have  two problems.

— Jamie Zawinski

Comment: A timeless classic

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use <some problem solving implementation>." Now they have two problems.

Comment: Some people when confronted with a problem don't think, they just post on StackOverflow

Comment: That is my personal all time favorite.

Comment: Some people don't understand regular expressions, and hate them because others do.

Comment: @Orbling, I've understood regular expressions deeply at different points, and I manage to get them to bend to my will (which doesn't will much). But beyond the macho idea that, "if you're not an expert, you should shut up," can't we begin to admit that regular expressions are horribly obtuse and that the densely packed syntax is pointless?

Comment: @Yar - I've never found the syntax obtuse personally, and the density is a good thing.  Why express something like a pattern match in a more verbose format?  Where clarity is required for something complicated, the extended mode can be used with comments.

Comment: @Matt Now two people have the same problem.

Answer (score 110):

> In theory, there is no difference
>   between theory and practice. But, in
>   practice, there is.

— Jan L. A. van de Snepscheut

Comment: I've also heard "The difference between theory and practice is smaller in theory than in practice."

Comment: Roger Pate's formulation is the one I heard, written by Olin Shivers in "History of T".  Paul Graham talks about it here: http://www.paulgraham.com/thist.html

Comment: I'd say if a theory doesn't translate to practice, then the theory is simply incomplete.

Answer (score 105):

> You can use an eraser on the drafting
>   table or a sledgehammer on the
>   construction site - Frank Lloyd Wright

Not exactly a programming quote but it most certainly applies.

Comment: Highly applicable IMO

Comment: goes to show how many metaphors software engineering draws from architecture... so much so that it _is_ called software arechitecture..

Comment: Luckily for us when most software goes wrong it doesn't collapse and kill people.

Comment: Except when it blows up an Ariane 5 (Flight 501), or doses people with lethally high levels of radiation...

Comment: @TomWij: The poster of this answer wants his comments below the quote, as shown by his rollback when you changed that the first time.  Is there a reason to disregard his wishes here?

Comment: I'm sorry for interrupting [your activity](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/209?tab=activity)...

Comment: @TomWij - Why do you have this uncontrollable urge to reformat everyone's answers?  Answers in this question are formatted equally with the person quoted inside the quote box as well as outside the quote box.  Do you intend to reformat EVERY answer??  WHY?

Comment: @TomWij: What?⁠

Comment: @Walter: It is nice to have some consistency; you'll note I've been doing that too, including here. I would disregard your preference of a "-" to "—" for that reason, but I simply don't see a reason for insisting your comment is at a particular place.

Comment: @Roger - It's MY answer.  I'm finding it hard to understand why you insist that my comment, in my answer, fit your expectations.

Comment: @Walter: This is a *community wiki* answer; from the [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq): "If you are not comfortable with the idea of your questions and answers being edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you."   That said, the consistency I'm talking about above is typographical consistency, not changing your intent.

Comment: @Roger - I completly understand that, but what makes YOUR formatting standard better than MINE??? Other than it's your preference?  Am I not part of this community as well?

Comment: @Walter: See also "Other people can edit my stuff?!" from the FAQ.

Comment: @Roger: The author name does not belong in the quote as you've been doing quite a few times, it isn't the author name that is quoted...

Comment: @TomWij: Source citations belong inside the blockquote according to most style manuals. For example, [this APA example](http://www.docstyles.com/apacrib.htm#Sec34) explicitly shows the parenthetical citation (which admittedly doesn't *exactly* match our use case) at the end of the last paragraph; but give the guideline: "Add the citation to the end of the block quote after the final punctuation." If there were prose in a paragraph beforehand, e.g. "The witty remark for which Blah blah is known:", that'd be different, but it's not the case here either.

Comment: @Roger Plate: I don't see how APA styles apply here, this is a website. Not a paper... The author his name does not fit in a blockquote, which denotes the thing being quoted. I don't see how the author name is part of the quote itself...

Comment: @TomWij: APA was just one example. You can put more inside the blockquote without implying it's being quoted.

Comment: @TomWij & @Roger - Thank you both for proving my point.  Until there is a documented standard that the SE communities are going to follow, I would suggest not imposing your standards on those who do not agree.

Comment: Ironically, I believe many of Frank Lloyd Wright's more convoluted buildings have fallen into disrepair.

Comment: @TomWij, @Walter, @Roger: Please refrain from dirtying this site with your metatalk. If I wanted to hear bickering, I would visit meta.stackoverflow.com. This is where you should be having this fascinating and timeless conversation.

Comment: @Yar: Oh please... The user won't be informed in that way, I guess you have listed me by mistake or else you would just add to this silly conversation. Apart from that, comments like these are hidden until you expand them so I wouldn't call it dirtying; but indeed, those users should go to the meta instead of responding if they have a problem with it.

Answer (score 103):

> Programming today is a race between software engineers striving to build bigger and better idiot-proof programs, and the Universe trying to produce bigger and better idiots. So far, the Universe is winning.

— Rick Cook

Answer (score 98):

> Measuring programming progress by lines of code is like measuring aircraft building progress by weight.
>     — Bill Gates

Comment: -- Bill Gates (http://www.softwarequotes.com/printableshowquotes.aspx?id=579)

Comment: This is true on multiple levels.  A gem.

Comment: The key difference being, of course, that the aircraft's final weight is known while the software's final LOC count is unknown.

Comment: So why do most Microsoft products give me this feeling that I'm chained by my foot to an airplane that is struggling to get off the runway?

Answer (score 86):

> There are 2 hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-1 errors.
>
> — Leon Bambrick (@[secretGeek](http://twitter.com/secretGeek/status/7269997868))

(Actually, everything from http://q4td.blogspot.com/search/label/programming seeing as I curate the list.)

Comment: I've never seen a quote point out how difficult naming things can be.  I feel a sudden solidarity.

Comment: That's 3 things. The first two are the original quote from Phil Karlton. @CodexArcanum. Naming things *well* is the trick.

Comment: @StuperUser *whooosh!* you missed the joke!

Comment: Took two seconds to get that after you pointed that out. Herp derp.

Answer (score 85):

> Nine people can't make a baby in a month.
>     — Fred Brooks, [*The Mythical Man-Month*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month)

Comment: -- Fred Brooks, in "The Mythical Man-Month"

Comment: technically: 18 people can't make a baby in a month

Comment: @HereBeWolves  or 10

Comment: @Here Be Wolves: Technically: 10 people can't make a baby in a month. ;)

Comment: What's wrong with 1 guy and 8 ladies?  Sounds just about right to me.

Comment: If we go for twins or triplets we need fewer ladies.

Comment: While the first baby will suffer 9 months latency, proper pipelining will continue to deliver 1 per month...

Comment: All these comments fails to reach the goal of the Quote. They're right but do it and your budget will go crazy because you expected just 1 baby.

Answer (score 82):

> We *should* forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.
>     — Donald Knuth, [Structured Programming with go to Statements](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.103.6084&rep=rep1&type=pdf), JACM Computing Surveys, Vol 6, No. 4, Dec. 1974, p.268

This is extracted from the below two paragraphs, which not only say *why* he comes to the above conclusion, but gives information on *how* to avoid this mistake:

> There is no doubt that the grail of efficiency leads to abuse.  Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered.  We *should* forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil.
>
> Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.  A good programmer will not be lulled into complacency by such reasoning, he will be wise to look carefully at the critical code; but only *after* that code has been identified.  It is often a mistake to make a priori judgments about what parts of a program are really critical, since the universal experience of programmers who have been using measurement tools has been that  their intuitive guesses fail. (…)

Comment: @Roger Pate: I suspect you're right, most people don't realize there is more to the quote.

Comment: Hope you don't mind that I included a bit more.  I think it's really important and maybe this will encourage more to read the full paper. :)

Comment: @Roger Pate:Not at all!

Comment: +1 Thanks for the full quote. I never know there was more to it.

Comment: It's great that you posted the entire quote. A lot of people just know the sort version and have no idea what Knuth actually meant by that.

Comment: Tinyurl for this answer that I found on SO: http://tinyurl.com/knuth-premature

Answer (score 80):

> Debuggers don't remove bugs. They only
>   show them in slow motion.

— Unknown

Comment: Or in many cases, make them stop appearing entirely.

Comment: @Graeme those cases are called Heisenbugs :)

Answer (score 76):

> The first 90% of the code accounts for the first 90% of the development time.
>   The remaining 10% of the code accounts for the other 90% of the development
>   time.

— [Tom Cargill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninety-ninety_rule)

Comment: Who said that originally?

Comment: Originally to me was a fellow classmate, but I do not know for certain who said it originally.

Comment: I don't know if this can even be attributed to a single person since it's obvious to anybody whose implemented a product from start to finish ... even just a little piece of shareware.

Comment: I think you'll find that 90% of the code takes 90% of the time, and the last 10% of the code takes the other 90% of the time.

Comment: Tom Cargill of Bell Labs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninety-ninety_rule

Comment: I know this: 20% mates drink 80% beer.

Comment: Personally, I'd say that the first 90% of the code accounts for the first 90% of the development time.  Then, the remaining 90% of the code accounts for the other 90% of the development time.

Comment: @Facticius haha, I like that.

Answer (score 70):

> If Java had true garbage collection, most programs would delete themselves upon execution.
>     — Robert Sewell

Comment: funny, just made me think of php.

Comment: @WalterJ89: Worry not! Up until PHP 5.3, PHP is refcounted.

Comment: I like this one!

Comment: @WalterJ89 Well, I see no reason to single out Java as opposed to COBOL, C++, VB, or others.

Answer (score 68):

> Computer Science is no more about computers than astronomy is about telescopes

— Edsger Dijkstra

Comment: Yes, but this is supposed to be about *programming*, not computer science. [sly grin]

Comment: Programming is just applying the knowledge gathered with computer science. You don't need a computer to program, at least not one like most are familiar with.

Comment: I've always felt that the most annoying thing about programming is that I can't separate it from computers.

Answer (score 56):

> If debugging is the process of
>   removing software bugs, then
>   programming must be the process of
>   putting them in.
>     — Edsger Dijkstra

Comment: That's why I like to refer to my job as *enbugging*.

Comment: And maintenance as *rebugging*?

Comment: *@JoeD* No, "bugwatching".

Answer (score 56):

> There are only two kinds of languages: the ones people complain about and the ones nobody uses

— Bjarne Stroustrup

Comment: bad excuse for C++ suckage

Comment: C# is an obvious counter-example.

Comment: And VB falls into both categories.

Answer (score 48):

> The best thing about a boolean is
>   even if you are wrong, you are only
>   off by a bit. - (Anonymous)

Comment: The worst thing being that you can't be more wrong ?

Answer (score 46):

> On two occasions I have been asked,
>   "Pray, Mr. Babbage, if you put into
>   the machine wrong figures, will the
>   right answers come out?" In one case a
>   member of the Upper, and in the other
>   a member of the Lower House put this
>   question. I am not able rightly to
>   apprehend the kind of confusion of
>   ideas that could provoke such a
>   question.
>     — Charles Babbage

Arguably the first documented case of a programmer encountering stupid user questions.

Comment: Sounds like a T-Shirt idea! "User Error: Fouling things up since 1832". (Date?)

Answer (score 42):

> It's all talk until the code runs.
>     — Ward Cunningham

Answer (score 42):

> I have always wished for my computer to be as easy to use as my telephone; my wish has come true because I can no longer figure out how to use my telephone

-- Bjarne Stroustrup

Answer (score 39):

> Commenting your code is like cleaning
>   your bathroom - you never want to do
>   it, but it really does create a more
>   pleasant experience for you and your
>   guests.

— Ryan Campbell

Comment: Meh...Most comments I've encountered in my life are written under the assumption that comments can make up for poorly written code..

Comment: You can clean the bathroom, but if the shower only has cold water and the sink has no soap it's going to be an unpleasant experience. Write code that reads easily rather than writing huge comments to explain things.

Comment: I actually find commenting quite enjoyable.  Sometimes I put important comments in neat little boxes made of asterisks and slashes.  Then again, I'm a freak.

Comment: I enjoy writing comments too, but you wouldn’t want to see my bathroom.

Comment: I was at a washroom once where there were really long-winded comments all over about how and why you should keep the washroom clean. It wasn't clean.

Answer (score 39):

> Unicode support is not a “feature”. It is expected behaviour.

Granted, it is very specific, but it is my favourite because obsolete character sets are just too widely used still...

Comment: Now you just have to argue about which unicode

Comment: @Martin: Not really, because conversion between the various kinds is lossless.

Comment: Aargh the pain! Why do I have to argue with a client that no, we can't "just" switch our whole infrastructure to Latin-1 to make it infinitesimally more convenient for him? "After all, nobody around *here* uses those weird special characters; can't be so hard, right?"

Answer (score 38):

> The fool wonders, the wise man asks.
>     — Benjamin Disraeli

Comment: [Made](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/39/whats-your-favourite-quote-about-programming/10451#10451) [one](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/39/whats-your-favourite-quote-about-programming/10452#10452) [per-answer.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/39/whats-your-favourite-quote-about-programming/10453#10453)

Comment: @TomWij: See my comment from when I edited this, these quotes have been split into separate answers.

Answer (score 35):

> Programming is like sex: one mistake and you have to support it for the rest of your life.
>     — Michael Sinz

Answer (score 34):

> Il semble que la perfection soit atteinte non quand il n'y a plus rien à
> ajouter, mais quand il n'y a plus rien à retrancher.
>
>   — Antoine de Saint-Exupéry, French writer (1900-1944), [*Terre des Hommes*](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Antoine_de_Saint-Exup%C3%A9ry#Terre_des_Hommes_.281939.29) (1939)
>
> (It would seem that perfection is attained not when there is nothing left to add, but when there is nothing left to take away.)

Comment: And it is also valid for music

Comment: [Perfection Is](http://web.archive.org/web/20070821042058/mpt.net.nz/archive/2006/11/27/perfection)

Comment: @David Kendal:  Nice!  Similarly, Henry David Thoreau said, "Simplify, Simplify."  Which always makes me think, "Simplify."

Answer (score 33):

> Java is to JavaScript as car is to carpet.
>   
>   — [Chris Heilmann](http://www.wait-till-i.com/2005/11/08/do-hr-people-even-read-their-job-ads-when-they-get-published/)

Comment: There is carpet in my car, so there is Javascript in Java?

Comment: @Keyo: Yeah, I thought of that take on it.  I still think the quote is really clever.

Answer (score 31):

As [formulated by Eric S. Raymond](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/writings/cathedral-bazaar/cathedral-bazaar/ar01s04.html):

> **Linus's Law**
>
> Given a large enough beta-tester and co-developer base, almost every problem will be characterized quickly and the fix obvious to someone.

Or, less formally,

> Given enough eyeballs, all bugs are shallow.

Comment: sounds a bit like the monkey / typewriter rule to me...

Comment: Why do Linux enthusiasts seem to spend more time repeating this quote than fixing the bugs?

Comment: Or, Atwood's slogan for StackOverflow, "None of us is as dumb as all of us". See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/09/stack-overflow-none-of-us-is-as-dumb-as-all-of-us.html

Answer (score 30):

> Keep it simple, stupid!

— [The KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: Is that specifically a programming quote?

Comment: No, it's a generally-applicable engineering principle.

Answer (score 30):

> There are 10 kinds of people in the
>   world — those who understand binary
>   and those who don't.

Comment: and those who confuse it with ternary

Comment: Every base is base 10.

Comment: You only have 10 votes for this? Lame :)

Comment: 10 in what base?

Comment: ¡ pick ur base !

Comment: @Larry: Then what about base 1? ;)

Comment: @g.f, base 1 isn't possible.

Comment: @Malfist: [Click.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_positional_numeral_systems#Base_one_.28unary_numeral_system.29)

Comment: @g.f, ok, but it's implementation is broken

Comment: there are 10 kinds of people , those who understand ternary , those who don't and those who keep saying this joke every where :) .

Comment: all your base 10 are belong to us

Comment: @Malfist: Yes it is. 0 = 0, 00 = 1, 000 = 2, 0000 = 3

Comment: @g.f, @Kevin: There is no such thing as “base 1”. The number system demonstrated by Kevin, which is often referred to as “base 1” or “unary”, is not a number base (but an entirely different notation). By definition, if “base 1” existed, it would only have the digit 0, and all numbers would be `sum(0*1^n)`, i.e., 0.

Comment: @Timwi: Did you follow the link above? Apparently opinions are divided about it - as soon as all mathematicians agree wether `0` belongs to `N` or not we might unify that too.

Comment: @g.f is not a question of maths, it's a question of naming. In any case, it's not a positional numbering system.

Answer (score 30):

> Should array indices start at 0 or 1?
>   My compromise of 0.5 was rejected
>   without, I thought, proper
>   consideration.
>     — Stan Kelly-Bootle

Answer (score 29):

> A clever person solves a problem. A wise person avoids it.
>     — Albert Einstein

Comment: **Programming** quote?

Comment: This quote is very relevant to programming

Answer (score 29):

> Being a good software engineer is 3% talent, 97% not being distracted by the internet.
>
> — Unknown, appropriated

Comment: That's not true at -- d'oh!

Comment: ...and 1% avoiding [fence post errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fencepost_error#Fencepost_error).

Answer (score 28):

> A computer is a stupid machine with the ability to do incredibly smart things, while computer programmers are smart people with the ability to do incredibly stupid things. They are, in short, a perfect match.
>     — Bill Bryson

Answer (score 25):

> What's the simplest thing that could
>   possibly work?

— Ward Cunningham

Comment: I was once at a programming competition, and time was almost up, and we couldn't get our last program to compile. So, in desperation, we deleted the bits that wouldn't compile, and ran the program. And it worked. Perfectly. To this day I have no explanation for how this could be the case because, by our measure, the part that we deleted was the part that was supposed to be doing the work.

Answer (score 25):

> All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection... Except for the problem of too many layers of indirection.

— David Wheeler

Answer (score 25):

> If you want to set off and go develop some grand new thing, you don't need millions of dollars of capitalization.  You need enough pizza and Diet Coke to stick in your refrigerator, a cheap PC to work on and the dedication to go through with it.
>     — John Carmack

Comment: Yep greatest quote I think so far, especially since Carmack showed multiple times (Commander Keen, Wolfenstein, Doom, Quake, etc) how to do it :)

Comment: @nils, one word: Daikatana :ducks:

Answer (score 25):

> Testing can only prove the presence of bugs, not their absence.

— Edsger W. Dijkstra

Comment: ... so let’s not bother! :)

Answer (score 23):

> There are two major products that come out of Berkeley: LSD and UNIX. We don't believe this to be a coincidence.
>
> *Jeremy S. Anderson*

Comment: Splitted as asked

Comment: This quote is wrong. Just wrong. See http://web.morons.org/feature/rants/bsdlsd.jsp

Comment: That's a shame because it's a great phrase.

Comment: @Neil: "If 'accurate' isn't a requirement, I could write an arbitrarily great phrase," to paraphrase another quote. :)

Comment: What exactly is LSD?

Comment: @hasen j, it's that little thing resembling a postmark you're holding under your tongue.

Comment: @hasen j, Traditionally, pounds, shillings, and pence, but nowadays a hallucinogen.

Comment: @hasen j: ++ for having the humility to ask that

Comment: I still don't understand what it is. Seriously, if it's something well known in your culture, don't just assume that every one in the world knows what it is.

Comment: @hasen j, it's an hallucynogen

Comment: @hasen j, see above for the answer. anyway I didn't think LSD was so little known. That's why I was joking. Don't take it personally ;-)

Comment: not helping ...

Comment: @hasen j, I give up, use wikipedia please...

Answer (score 23):

> I don't care if it works on your machine! We are not shipping your machine!

-- Vidiu Platon (whoever that is)

Comment: First see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/39/whats-your-favourite-programming-quote/1456#1456

Comment: Yeah, I've put this badge on at least one project: http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0128776ff992970c-pi

Answer (score 23):

> When all you have is a hammer, everything starts to look like a nail

Comment: Attributed to Abraham Maslow (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_all_you_have_is_a_hammer,_everything_looks_like_a_nail)

Comment: This quote is true, but many times the converse is also true: until you have a hammer, nails are an unsolvable problem.

Comment: @Yar Turn your pliers sideways.

Comment: Thanks @Mark C that worked, but now the program quits with no stacktrace...

Comment: @Yar If enough of the nail is sticking out, you can pull it out with your pliers. Not all hammers have a notched end, and some nails can't be pulled out like that (so you need a nail pull).

Answer (score 21):

> Good code is its own best documentation. As you're about to add a comment, ask yourself, 'How can I improve the code so that this comment isn't needed?' Improve the code and then document it to make it even clearer.

-Steve McConnell

Answer (score 21):

> There are two ways of constructing a software design: One way is to make it so simple that there are obviously no deficiencies, and the other way is to make it so complicated that there are no obvious deficiencies.

— C.A.R. Hoare

Answer (score 20):

> A computer lets you make more
>   mistakes faster than any invention in
>   human history—with the possible
>   exceptions of handguns and tequila.
>     — Mitch Ratcliffe

Comment: I had a specific answer in mind for my bounty originally, but I discovered you can't apply them instantly!  So I let it runs its course, and even though there's about a day left, this is my favorite answer from the past week.  One I'd heard before, but never knew who said it.  Thanks!

Comment: @RogerP: What was your specific answer? Is it in the big thread?

Comment: @Mark: http://tinyurl.com/knuth-premature

Comment: *@RogerP*: You are too easy, trying to give bounties for answers you already know!

Answer (score 19):

> A programmer is a device for turning
>   caffeine into code.

(Not original to me, but associated with me through appearances on DotNetRocks etc. Lifted from a Usenet sig, I long ago forgot whose, which was no doubt inspired by [Paul Erdos](http://greatsayings.blogspot.com/2008/03/you-dont-have-to-be-rocket-scientist-to.html).)

Comment: Erdõs -- indeed!  My grandfather (who knew him!) was fond of the one about mathematicians and coffee.

Comment: @khedron: Ahem. It’s Erdős, not Erdõs.

Comment: @Timwi: My apologies!

Answer (score 19):

> There, it should work now.
>
> — All programmers

Answer (score 18):

> You wanted a banana but what you got was a gorilla holding the banana and the entire jungle.
>   
>   — Joe Armstrong on object-oriented programming

Comment: Still laughing... |)

Comment: wouldn't that be more true of VMs ?

Comment: The term 'OO' was invented by Smalltalkers, and Smalltalk runs on a VM and is often deployed as a VM image.

Answer (score 18):

> A programmer started to cuss
>   Because getting to sleep was a fuss
>   As he lay there in bed
>   Looping 'round in his head
>   was: `while(!asleep()) sheep++;`

Not quite a quote as such, but I little limerick I've always liked.

Source [piercings - bash.org/?845468](http://bash.org/?845468)

Comment: quite brilliant!

Comment: Limerick fans should also check out http://poetry.about.com/od/poetryplay/l/blwakawaka.htm

Answer (score 18):

> Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it. 
>   
>   — [Donald Knuth](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/faq.html)

Answer (score 18):

> Any fool can write code that a
>   computer can understand. Good
>   programmers write code that humans can
>   understand.

Martin Fowler (in his book [*Refactoring*](http://martinfowler.com/books.html#refactoring))

Answer (score 17):

My old answer from SO:

> If the code and the comments disagree, then both are probably wrong.

Another good website: ["Quotes about Tech Writing"](http://www.sysprog.net/programming-quotes/)

Comment: So you need code, comments, and something else? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_modular_redundancy

Answer (score 17):

> Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.

-- Arthur C. Clarke

Comment: "Any sufficiently advanced magic is indistinguishable from technology" — Larry Niven.

Comment: "Any technology which is distinguishable from magic is insufficiently advanced." (Can't remember.)

Comment: "Any sufficiently advanced being can distinguish technology from magic."

Comment: Any sufficiently advanced being cannot tell magic from technology.

Comment: Sufficiently advanced incompetence is indistinguishable from malice.

Answer (score 14):

To understand recursion, you first need to understand recursion

Answer (score 13):

> Software is like sex: it's better when it's free.

— Linus Torvalds

Comment: Can you split this in two different answers so that they can be voted independently?

Comment: The real question is, how did Linus come to find this out?

Comment: [citation needed] :-)

Comment: @Stefano Palazzo: Read his autobiography "Just For Fun". Oh, and in case you meant the "sex is better when it's free"-part...ahm...that's OT here. ;)

Comment: When i wrote this comment, this answer was a completely different one: see revisions. (It used to read "There are two major products that come out of Berkeley: LSD and UNIX. We don't believe this to be a coincidence.") – isn't it quite bad form to write and answer, which gets voted up, and change it completely, even when it's community wiki?

Comment: I was asked to split it, so it's not completely my fault :P. Moreover, most of the upvotes came after the split. More-moreover it was already split when you posted that comment, as you can see in "Last edit Sep 27" :P .

Comment: Well commenting here doesn't seem to be *thread safe*. :-) Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Software is like sex because it's never *really* free.

Answer (score 13):

> "For a successful technology, reality
>   must take precedence over public
>   relations, for nature cannot be
>   fooled."

-Richard Feynman
(Rogers' Commission Report into the Challenger Crash, Appendix F - Personal Observations on Reliability of Shuttle)

More succinctly:

> "You can't lie to the compiler."

-Andrew Stevenson

Comment: ...or at least if you *do* lie to the compiler, it will get its revenge.

Comment: That story still galls me. Imagine that, Dr. Richard Feynman, according to the book I read, had to *threaten to withhold his signature* unless his account of the accident was included in the official report. It was included as an appendix, so as to say, "The official investigation is over, and now here is some speculation from this eccentric."

Answer (score 13):

> On the seventh day, God said, "Ship it!  We'll release patches later."
>   
>   — Josh Flachsbart

Answer (score 12):

> The real question is not whether
>   machines think but whether men do.

— B. F. Skinner

Related more to AI than to simple programming, but I still like it.

Answer (score 11):

Not really a programming quote, more of an IT one, but one that my A-Level IT teacher drummed into me aged 16:

> Typing is no substitute for Thinking

Comment: Admirably ambiguous.

Comment: That comment is ambiguous,hence admirable :P

Answer (score 11):

> The difficulty of a bug can be
>   measured as the distance, in lines of
>   code, from the cause of a bug to the
>   visible symptom of a bug.

[The Klophaus Equation of Bug Difficulty](http://rustyklophaus.com/articles/20070811-TheKlophausEquationOfBugDifficulty.html)

Comment: The problem is that you don't know how difficult a bug is until you find it.

Answer (score 11):

#### Relationship between length and quality

> If you want me to give you a two-hour presentation, I am ready today.  If you want only a five-minute speech, it will take me two weeks to prepare.
>   
>   — Mark Twain

The shortest version:

> If I had more time, I would have written a shorter letter.
>   
>   — Marcus T. Cicero

The near-perfectionist's version:

> You know that I write slowly. This is chiefly because I am never satisfied until I have said as much as possible in a few words, and writing briefly takes far more time than writing at length.
>   
>   — Karl Friedrich Gauss

[Several more](http://dangerousintersection.org/2006/04/12/more-time-shorter-letter/) discuss this concept from various angles.

Answer (score 11):

> Crockford is the sole user of the super-strict equality operator (====), which either returns true or kicks you in the balls.

Answer (score 10):

> A good algorithm is like a sharp knife - it does exactly what it is supposed to do with a minimum amount of applied effort. Using the wrong algorithm to solve a problem is trying to cut a steak with a screwdriver: you may eventually get a digestible result, but you will expend considerable more effort than necessary, and the result is unlikely to be aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: A mouthful, but good. Like steak!

Answer (score 10):

> Open source is free only if your time costs nothing

Heard it from a guy I worked with. Don't know who came up with this.

Comment: That's not so true, though.

Comment: @Mark Why? (ps. it's a translation from Hebrew, and "free" is translated from a word that means "at no charge" and not "liberated/released/etc").

Comment: I doesn't seem true because skilled programmers take on open source projects in their spare time, even though they could be working on extra "paid" projects instead.

Comment: @Mark That's not what I meant... This quote is about the misconception that choosing an open source product over a commercial one is better because you don't have to pay for license (use, not develop). This is stupid, of course, since most of the time whatever you saved in licences you pay in programmer time due to lack of support and/or using products that are not good enough. There *are* good reasons to use OS. License price, I think, is not one of them.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. It seemed like it was talking about the programmers! This is along the lines of what you are saying: http://blog.bitquabit.com/2009/06/30/one-which-i-say-open-source-software-sucks/

Comment: @Mark Nice! What is this blog?

Comment: You're welcome! It is the blog of a Fog Creek developer, and it is where I read this article: http://blog.bitquabit.com/2009/07/01/one-which-i-call-out-hacker-news/

Comment: @Mark *panics* Where is the posts RSS?!

Comment: I don't use RSS, but I think you're trying to get a feed from that page. Try this: http://profy.com/2007/09/30/7-tools-to-make-an-rss-feed-of-any-website/

Comment: @Mark I know these services, I was hoping for built in option.

Comment: My quote file attributes this to JWZ.

Answer (score 9):

> Computers are useless.  They can only give you answers.
>     — Pablo Picasso

Comment: Considering Picasso died in 1973, I'm highly doubtful that he actually said this..

Comment: "The first electronic computers were developed in the mid-20th century (1940–1945)" and Intel was already creating CPUs in 1971 (Intel 4004). So it doesn't make it impossible.

Comment: @Billy There was a lot of talk amongst academics about the possibilities of computers at the time.

Answer (score 9):

> A few months writing code can save you a few hours in design.

Which is modified from:

> A few months in the laboratory can save you a few hours in the library.

Comment: what does it mean by that ???

Comment: @Sarawut Positwinyu: It's a backwards way of saying 'do your research before doing your work'.

Answer (score 9):

Be nice to nerds. Chances are you'll end up working for one. - Bill Gates

The problem with quick and dirty...is that dirty remains long after quick has been forgotten. - Steve C McConnell

My site [SoftwareQuotes.com](http://www.SoftwareQuotes.com) is full of quotations about programming and software development.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it wasn't Bill Gates who made that quote

Comment: I remember it being attributed to him, along with a bunch of others that shouldn't be. Who was it?

Answer (score 9):

> A normal person believes a kilobyte is 1000 bytes, a coder believes a kilometer is 1024 meters.

-Unknown

Answer (score 9):

> [C++: an octopus made by nailing extra
>   legs onto a dog.](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?CeePlusPlus)

Answer (score 9):

It should be noted that no ethically-trained software engineer would ever consent to write a DestroyBaghdad procedure. Basic professional ethics would instead require him to write a DestroyCity procedure, to which Baghdad could be given as a parameter.

Nathaniel Borenstein

Answer (score 8):

[image: xkcd "Compiling"]

Comment: Can you fix this so we don't have to click the link to see the quote please?

Comment: http://delphi.org/2008/09/the-worst-thing-about-delphi/

Comment: xkcd has some great stuff, but this is below average.

Answer (score 8):

> Why fix an old bug if you can write three new ones in the same time?

— David Kastrup

Answer (score 7):

Quoting [Kent Beck](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast):

> Make It Work 
>   Make It Right 
>   Make It Fast

Comment: Pick 2............

Comment: Whew! For a minute there I thought you had written *"Glenn"* Beck... ;-)

Answer (score 7):

> ...  one of the main causes of the fall of the Roman Empire was that, lacking zero, they had no way to indicate successful termination of their C programs.

-- Robert Firth

Answer (score 7):

> Real Programmers don't comment their code. If it was hard to write, it should be hard to understand.
>     — [Tom Van Vleck](http://www.multicians.org/thvv/realprogs.html)

Comment: It's called code for a reason :)

Comment: While I love this quote, I tend to find the people maintaining my code disagree with it :)

Answer (score 7):

> Anyone attempting to produce random numbers by purely arithmetic means is, of course, in a state of sin.
>     — John von Neumann

Answer (score 7):

> Those who try to build idiot-proof systems always underestimate the persistence and ingenuity of idiots.

— Anon

Answer (score 7):

> One accurate measurement is worth more
>   than a thousand expert opinions.

*Admiral Grace Hopper*

Answer (score 6):

> I am one of those culprits who created the problem.  I used to write those programs back in the '60s and '70s, and was so proud of the fact that I was able to squeeze a few elements of space by not having to put '19' before the year.

-- Alan Greenspan, former Federal Reserve chair

Answer (score 6):

> How do we convince people that in programming simplicity and clarity—in short: what mathematicians call "elegance"—are not a dispensable luxury, but a crucial matter that decides between success and failure?

— [Edsger W. Dijkstra](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD06xx/EWD648.html)

Comment: Props to the guy who [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes/75903#75903) this on SO

Comment: Answer: The same way you convince people that simplicity and clarity are essential to good writing!

Answer (score 6):

> A beautiful program is like a
>   beautiful theorem: It does the job
>   elegantly. It has a simple and
>   perspicuous structure; people say,
>   “Oh, yes. I see that’s the way to do
>   it.”

-- Butler Lampson

Answer (score 6):

Every time I ask developers why their shiny new C# .NET version isn't nearly as fast and smooth as the old C/C++ version, I'm thinking of:

> The most amazing achievement of the computer software industry is its continuing cancellation of the steady and staggering gains made by the computer hardware industry.
>     — [Henry Petroski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Petroski)

But they just tell me to shut up while they plaster on yet another level of abstraction...

Comment: Anders Hejlsberg also has a quote, which I don't remember in his exact words, that the goal of a language is to *add* layers of abstraction, not to move the window of abstraction upwards. You simply don't agree with the design goals of the platform.

Answer (score 6):

> Programming is one of the most
>   difficult branches of applied
>   mathematics; the poorer mathematicians
>   had better remain pure mathematicians

— Edsger W. Dijkstra

Comment: I find that incredibly pompous.

Comment: @Mark: "You probably know that arrogance, in computer science, is measured in nanodijkstras." — Alan Kay, keynote speech at OOPSLA 1997

Comment: @RogerP Ah yes, I had forgotten that one.

Comment: "Programmers are bozos" -- my high school math teacher.

Answer (score 6):

> "The complexity you remove can never
>   fail" 
>   -- Burt Rutan on the  Ansari X Prize

Answer (score 5):

> There is always one more bug.
>   
>   — Lubarsky's Law of Cybernetic Entomology

Answer (score 5):

> The art of simplicity is a puzzle of
>   complexity.

*Doug Horton*

Answer (score 5):

"It worked on MY computer!"
    -anon

"Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute."
    - Abelson and Sussman, from "The structure and interpretation of computer programs"

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/39/whats-your-favourite-programming-quote/1523#1523

Answer (score 5):

The best code is no code at all

Comment: Butterflies!...

Comment: I think that's a corruption of the Taligent marketing catchphrase "there is no code faster than no code".

Answer (score 5):

> Programmers are optimists by nature, they also have a keen eye for the downside. A hyperactive imagination for disaster scenarios is a professional asset; they have to think through everything that can go wrong in order to practice their craft.

-- Scott Rosenberg

Answer (score 5):

Not really about programming, but...

> You can't wait for inspiration. You have to go after it with a club.
>   
>   — Jack London

Answer (score 5):

It's not about programming *per se,* but by a famous programmer:

> The best way to predict the future is to invent it.
>   
>   — Alan Kay

Which is usually a good thing to remind myself to get moving and do things.

Answer (score 5):

> Kurzfristige Hacks tendieren dazu, langfristige Lösungen zu werden.
>   
>   — Bodo Tasche

*Translated:* Current hacks tend to be long-term solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Make everything as simple as possible, but *not simpler*.

-- Albert Einstein (for me, via Scott Myers). Emphasis added.

Comment: I know the question says one quote per answer, but I'm starting to think grouping similar topics (e.g. this with KISS) would be better.

Answer (score 5):

> A language that doesn't have everything is actually easier to program in than some that do.
>   
>   — Dennis M. Ritchie

Comment: Java is getting there.

Answer (score 4):

> “ Copy and paste is a design error. ”
>    -- David Parnas

Comment: Could you explain what he means by that?

Comment: @ Mark C - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/04/a-modest-proposal-for-the-copy-and-paste-school-of-code-reuse.html

Answer (score 4):

[Write once, debug everywhere](http://blog.jgc.org/2007/10/write-once-debug-everywhere.html).

Answer (score 4):

Well, not my favorite but...

> If it is not broken, don't fix it

Comment: also known as "don't ever refactor"

Comment: If it needs a refactor, it's broken :-)

Comment: My colleague has a T-shirt that says: "Engineer's motto: If it ain't broke, take it apart and fix it!"

Answer (score 4):

> I abhor a system designed for the
>   "user," if that word is a coded
>   pejorative meaning "stupid and
>   unsophisticated."

Ken Thompson

Answer (score 4):

> Debugging is like farting — it's not so bad when it's your own code.

Comment: It's unknown who originally put forth this piece of wisdom; I took it from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes/344812#344812).

Answer (score 4):

> Plans are worthless, but planning is everything.
>     — Dwight D. Eisenhower

Comment: Ah, yes, the difference between plans and planning! Excellent!

Answer (score 4):

My favourites have already been posted, so here's something I thought of one day at work:

> In Soviet Russia, exception throws *YOU!!*

Comment: I can almost hear the russian accent in my head.

Comment: In Soviet Russia, boss give orders YOU!

Comment: In Soviet Russia, bug fixes you.

Answer (score 4):

> Einstein argued that there must be simplified explanations of nature, because God is not capricious or arbitrary. No such faith comforts the software engineer. 
>   
>   — Fred Brooks, ["No Silver Bullet"](http://www.virtualschool.edu/mon/SoftwareEngineering/BrooksNoSilverBullet.html)

Answer (score 4):

From my first programming class (FORTRAN IV):

> What is a computer?
>   It it a box with a little man in it.
>   This man is blazing fast. He can do millions of instructions per second.
>   But he is myopic. He's so myopic that he can see only one instruction at a time.
>   He's also not very smart, he'll attempt to do exactly what you tell him to do.

This has become the base of my philosophy of programming and debugging.

Answer (score 4):

> 2 + 2 = 5, for sufficiently large values of 2.

— Anon

Answer (score 4):

> Software is hard.

-- Donald Knuth

Comment: Let’s go typesetting!

Answer (score 4):

> If you fail to plan, you plan to fail

-My c# Teacher (not sure where he heard it from!)

Comment: I recently saw this [attributed](http://www.google.com/search?q=alan+lakein+planning) to [Alan Lakein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Lakein), but it is simple enough to have been around for a long time (folk reversals).

Comment: I heard this all the way through secondary school.

Answer (score 4):

> Knowledge is proud that it knows so
>   much; wisdom is humble that it knows
>   no more.

--William Cowper

Comment: I've heard something similar.  "Knowledge is knowing what is right, wisdom is doing what is right".  Not sure who said it, I think it's an old Chinese saying that has been translated.

Answer (score 3):

In Hebrew there's a saying (mostly by army conscripted programmers):

> באג בדיזיין -> זין בדיבאג

Which is an anagram, and it roughly translates to

> Bugs in the design -> you're f^#ked while debugging

Comment: I don't think there's any way to translate the humor to English, but nice quote.

Comment: It kind of relies on the meaning of "zign".

Answer (score 3):

> Fail Quickly

*--Unknown*

Comment: The perfect match for "Avoid success!"

Answer (score 3):

It works on my machine

Comment: Favorite to hate, of course :-)

Answer (score 3):

> /* You are not expected to understand this. */

Comment in Sixth Edition Unix.

Comment: I've witnessed that one in the original source code! (I was three at the time...) But I do treasure my copy of the annotated Version 6 Source Code from the University of New South Wales.

Comment: Is that a general comment or does it appear at a certain point?

Comment: @Mark: It referred to a specific section of code.  I forget what that section was doing.

Answer (score 3):

> Let me re-assert that the question of whether there are limitations in principle of what problems man can make machines solve for him as compared to his own ability to solve problems, really is a technical question in recursive function theory.
>
> — John McCarthy

Answer (score 3):

> If it wasn't for the last minute, nothing would get done.

*—Supposedly from "Murphy's Laws"; [see here](http://www.murphys-laws.com/murphy/murphy-commerce.html)*

Although I can do plenty of things without any pressure (like post answers here), I need a hint of fear to do what I'm supposed to be doing (like my homework).

Answer (score 3):

> I don't understand why cheerleaders
>   won't talk to me. Maybe I don't throw
>   five touchdowns against Newport High,
>   but let's see one of those football
>   morons program in assembly language!
>   
>   — Chris Lipe

Answer (score 3):

> It's OK to figure out murder
>   mysteries, but you shouldn't need to
>   figure out code. You should be able to read it.

-- Steve McConnell

Answer (score 3):

> Profanity is the one language all
>   programmers know best.

-- Anonymous

Answer (score 3):

> It should be noted that no ethically-trained software engineer would ever consent to write a DestroyBaghdad procedure. Basic professional ethics would instead require him to write a DestroyCity procedure, to which Baghdad could be given as a parameter.

<sup>Nathaniel Borenstein</sup>

Comment: Dupe: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/39/whats-your-favourite-quote-about-programming/14249#14249

Answer (score 2):

> Get into a rut early: Do the same process the same way. Accumulate idioms. Standardize. The only difference(!) between Shakespeare and you was the size of his idiom list - not the size of his vocabulary.

--Alan J. Perlis

Answer (score 2):

> Being able to get a machine to do what you want is the closest thing we've got in technology to adolescent wish-fulfillment.
>   
>   — [Guy Steele](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_L._Steele,_Jr.) in *Coders at Work*

Answer (score 2):

> Knowledge is knowledge. And viceversa.

From a T-shirt.

Answer (score 2):

> It would seem that perfection is attained not when no more can be added, but when no more can be removed.
>
> Antoine de Saint-Exupery

Comment: Dupe of http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/39/whats-your-favourite-programming-quote/1617#1617

Answer (score 2):

```
to understand recursion you must first understand recursion
```

Comment: At first that was just corny, but later it dawned on me that the very sentence teaches recursion.

Comment: To first understad mutual exclusion you must first forget everything you know about exclusive mutuality, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

> Linux is only free if your time has no value.

> Memory is like an orgasm. It's a lot better if you don't have to fake it.
>   
>   — Seymour Cray on virtual memory

Comment: May I know why it was down-voted?

Comment: Either you made some Linux user angry or someone didn't like having many quotes in one answer.

Comment: Recursion was a [duplicate](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/39/whats-your-favourite-quote-about-programming/1553#1553), so I removed it.  The downvote could've simply been "I don't like this quote," but it would also fit better with the other answers if you move one of the two remaining quotes.

Answer (score 2):

COBOL can be cured if caught early.

-- From Programming classes

Answer (score 2):

> In C++ it’s harder to shoot yourself in the foot, but when you do, you blow off your whole leg.
>   
>   — Bjarne Stroustrup

Comment: You made me think of the ["shoot yourself in the foot"](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/susan/joke/foot.htm) jokes. Also see [What Is the Most Spectacular Way to Shoot Yourself in the Foot with C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174892/what-is-the-most-spectacular-way-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-with-c)

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking me to do is like trying to put the toothpaste back in the tube. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Vision without action is a daydream. 
Action without vision is a nightmare.

proverb from japan

Answer (score 2):

A quote on recursion and programming in general I came up with today.

> Only fools believe in foolproof
>   systems.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if he's the originator of this quote, but I attended a session at a conference once where Alex Pukinskis said this and I love it!

> Untested code has no business value -
>   Alex Pukinskis

Answer (score 1):

This isn't strictly a programming quote and I don't recall where I first heard it, but I've repeated it plenty of times on the job:

> If you don't test it, it doesn't work.

Comment: True. Ohh, so true

Answer (score 1):

> Release early. Release often. *-- Eric S. Raymond*

Comment: Popularized by Eric S. Raymond in "The Cathedral and the Bazaar" (http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/cathedral-bazaar/cathedral-bazaar/). The third part of ESR's quote is "And listen to your customers."

Answer (score 1):

> I'll call him Mel, because that was his name.

From [The story of Mel](http://www.pbm.com/~lindahl/mel.html)

Comment: "I have often felt that programming is an art form, whose real value can only be appreciated by another versed in the same arcane art; there are lovely gems and brilliant coups hidden from human view and admiration, sometimes forever, by the very nature of the process. You can learn a lot about an individual just by reading through his code, even in hexadecimal. Mel was, I think, an unsung genius. "

Comment: The story is entertaining, but this isn't a good quote: it's obscure and uninteresting.

Comment: *@Roger:* Well, he can use my quote and then you can upvote.

Comment: I tend to like short, easy to remember, quotes. Somehow, when I first read the Story of Mel this line got stuck in my head :-)

Comment: @Mark: Whatever you're doing with italics on the names in your comments is screwing up comment notification.

Comment: @Roger Really? You mean it's not working? I just do (star)At-Roger(colon)(star).

Comment: @Mark: I did double check by going through my reply history, and there is no entry on Oct 10.  (Did that before the comment today, since it was nearly 2 weeks ago. ;)

Comment: @RogerP That means all my other formatted replies didn't work either. Do you think it's the colon or the italics? We could test right now. I'll try it in chat first.

Comment: @Mark: Given that I use a colon and you apparently get the notifications... :P The italics probably disrupts the matching, which looks for @ and (I strongly suspect) uses the source rather than the marked-up comment.  [ *How do comment replies work?* ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/54262)

Comment: @RogerP: Well, it could be only when you use *both*, but of course that's far-fetched.

Answer (score 1):

"Test what you fly, fly what you test."

Answer (score 1):

> The required techniques of effective reasoning are pretty formal, but as long as programming is done by people that don't master them, the software crisis will remain with us and will be considered an incurable disease. And you know what incurable diseases do: they invite the quacks and charlatans in, who in this case take the form of Software Engineering gurus.

-- Dijkstra

Comment: That is interesting quote.

Answer (score 1):

> Simplicity is prerequisite for reliability.

-- Edsger W. Dijkstra

Answer (score 1):

> Education: that which reveals to the wise, and conceals from the stupid, the vast limits of their knowledge.
>     — Mark Twain

Answer (score 1):

#### Concentrate Your Effort

> Don't write too much. Concentrate your sweat on one story, rather than dissipate it over a dozen.
>
> *Jack London*

---

Somehow, I missed the (paraphrased, shorter) duplicate of this one:

#### Be Diligent

> Don't loaf and invite inspiration; light out after it with a club, and if you don't get it you will nonetheless get something that looks remarkably like it."

Part of [one quote](http://www.kirjasto.sci.fi/jlondon.htm); I split them to narrow down the topic.

Answer (score 1):

> You should go home if you are thinking suicidal thoughts.
>   
>   — Robert Read, ["How to be a Programmer"](http://samizdat.mines.edu/howto/HowToBeAProgrammer.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had a teacher that would tell students who were getting ahead of themselves this:

> You don't know what you don't know

I can't say for sure if it's his quote or something he picked up from somewhere else.

Comment: See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known_unknown

Comment: Not necessarily. There is what you know you know, what you know you don't know (e.g. how to fly a helicopter), and what you don't know you don't know. Then for some there is what they don't know they know.

Answer (score 1):

> Just use string you G-- d---ed savages!

during debate about merits of  `char[]` vs `string`

Answer (score 1):

"That's not the way I would have done it"

Answer (score 1):

By Mike Williams, one of the creators of Erlang:

1. Find the right methods—Design by Prototyping.
2. It is not good enough to have ideas, you must also be able to implement them and know they work.
3. Make mistakes on a small scale, not in a production project.

Answer (score 1):

> OOP to me means only messaging, local 
>   retention and protection and hiding of
>   state-process, and extreme
>   late-binding of all things. It can be
>   done in Smalltalk and in LISP. There
>   are possibly other systems in which
>   this is possible, but I’m not aware of
>   them.

-- Alan Kay

Answer (score 1):

> Only wimps use tape backup: real men
>   just upload their important stuff on
>   ftp, and let the rest of the world
>   mirror it ;)

-- Linus Torvalds

Comment: ftp? Doesn't he mean git?

Answer (score 1):

> You can't trust code that you did not totally create yourself.  (Especially code from companies that employ people like me.)
>   
>   — Ken Thompson, ["Reflections on Trusting Trust"](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/ken/trust.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
double value; /* or your money back! */
short changed; /* so triple your money back! */
```

cons.c on perl source tree

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could make Lust and Gluttony helpful but Sloth, Pride and Envy are certainly great for programmers." ~ [Kenneth Clowes](http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~kclowes/)

Answer (score 1):

> There is no object-oriented problem that cannot be solved by adding a layer of indirection, except, of course, too many layers of indirection.

-- From "The Art of Unit Testing" Roy Osherove (attributed to an unnamed source)

Comment: David Wheeler maybe? http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/39/whats-your-favourite-quote-about-programming/978#978

Answer (score 1):

> If you can't measure it, you can't
>   improve it.

<sup>Lord Kelvin</sup>

Answer (score 1):

> Don't code today what you can't debug tomorrow

from this [blog](http://ariya.blogspot.com/)'s title

Answer (score 1):

> The best indication of software
>   quality is consistent indentation

I read this when I was following up footnotes in [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) once but I've not been able to find it since, so a) I can't attribute it and b) I am writing from memory, and more than likely paraphrasing. I have, however, found it to be true.

Comment: ironic that people don't use IDEs with automatic indentation, then.

Answer (score 1):

> Progress isn't made by early risers. It's made by lazy men trying to find easier ways to do something.

-Robert Heinlein

Answer (score 0):

> Minimal Functionality to the desktop as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> As a general rule, the most successful man in life is the man who has the best information.
>     — Benjamin Disraeli

Answer (score 0):

> The whole history of this invention has been a struggle against time.
>     — Charles Babbage on the Analytical Engine, 1837

Answer (score 0):

#### Skill Appreciates Skill

(Or, It Takes One to Know One)

> I have often felt that programming is an art form,
> whose real value can only be appreciated
> by another versed in the same arcane art;
> there are lovely gems and brilliant coups
> hidden from human view and admiration, sometimes forever,
> by the very nature of the process.
> You can learn a lot about an individual
> just by reading through his code, even in hexadecimal.

From [The Story of Mel, a Real Programmer](http://foldoc.org/The+Story+of+Mel) (free verse version)

I had no idea there was actually a short [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_Kaye) with links to both prose and verse versions of the story, along with other information.

Answer (score 0):

> Entia non sunt multiplicanda praeter necessitatem
>
> (Keep it simple, stupid)

Years ago I ran across a poster that had the Latin expression with the English translation under it.

Comment: I don't think it's ironic, because the latin is "Occam's Razor" and most people, myself included, won't understand the Latin.

Comment: @Mark - Ah, thanks. I didn't realize it was Occam's Razor. "Entities must not be multiplied beyond necessity" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor).

Answer (score 0):

Keep it Simple!

Comment: Duplicate of http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/39/whats-your-favourite-quote-about-programming/87#87

Answer (score 0):

"Real programmers don't see code, they see trees."

Answer (score 0):

> Programmers don't quit, they just go offline. :)

Answer (score 0):

XML is like violence - if it doesn’t solve your problems, you are not using enough of it.

Comment: Children, please don't forget that violence is no solution...it's an instrument to accomplish a solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Programming is an art form that fights back

-- Unknown

*Note: especially when you're oncall...*

Answer (score 0):

True story:

I was doing a project for school in c++ and needless to say there was some compiler wrestling.  As I got more pissed of I started naming my test functions shit with fuck variants for variables.  At some point to every-bodies amusement I yelled "Why isn't this fuck pointing to shit?!?!?"

Answer (score -1):

> Impossible is Nothing

Although belongs to Adidas, but fits Software development well.

Comment: This is especially priceless when your boss comes armed with *that*, and a change request which is essentially the halting problem. "I don't care about your fancy-schmancy CS theory; you *will* make it work, to be delivered next week, because I already billed the client for it. Impossible is nothing, right? RIGHT!?" (not surprisingly, that person is no longer my boss)

Comment: Yes right, and really impossible is nothing. Why should one posses a CS Degree if he isn't capable to make things work the way they should.

Answer (score -1):

> Comments in code are like sex. When
>   they are good -- it's very, very good.
>   But when they are bad, they are better
>   than nothing.

-- Anonymous

Comment: "Out of date and now just misleading" falls under "bad" and that's even worse than nothing.